# Supply amount exceed total supply! Why the quantity supply shown 1.00 E+59

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, airdrop

[image: the quantity amount over the total supply, shown 1E +59] 
the quantity amount over the total supply,  shown 1E +59
Airdrop solidity code maybe got something problem, does someone had idea??
Can't check for token Holder,  "Sorry, We Are Unable To Generate The Token Holders Chart For This Token Contract"

Here is contract address: [0x437e46108cc18299ee48074de8db7d99d6703a08](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x437e46108cc18299ee48074de8db7d99d6703a08#balances)

Comment: contract address, please!

Comment: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x437e46108cc18299ee48074de8db7d99d6703a08#balances

Comment: @MaheshRajput https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x437e46108cc18299ee48074de8db7d99d6703a08#balances this is on Ropsten Etherscan net.

Comment: It is more helpful to find where is the problem if you can provide token contract code.

Comment: @MaheshRajput bro, pls drop your email, I sent a copy for you. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of taking a photo of your laptop with a camera (which might reveal a lot about your personal life, just from the reflection, for example), you could: 1. print the screen and paste the image here. 2. copy-paste the screen contents in here.

Answer (score 2):

For [ERC20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) tokens `balanceOf()` and `totalSupply()` are separate functions.

The standard indicates the functionality we should expect but it is up to the developer to enforce the correct semantic of the functions.

From the magnitud of the numbers it is close to `(2**256 - 1) / 10**18 = 1.157920892373162e+59`, a possibility is that some operation caused an underflow. If you do not use SafeMath library likely this is the case.